# Ubuntu Frame - wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk high CPU consume

Tags: cpu, system, kiosk

Good Morning,

I installed correctly Ubuntu-Frame on my machine, I used the Ubuntu [documentation](https://mir-server.io/docs/run-ubuntu-frame-on-your-device) to do it,

It worked fine, and it was easy to do, in fact I did it with a RP4 the last time and works perfect, the thing is that i'm using now a different PC, using a different CPU, and when I play a website with a embeeded video, the CPU performance rises up to more than a 100%, which I don't know why,

[Here is the cpu usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMgW9.png)

[Here are the specs of the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg9CA.png)

As you can see, the **WPEWebProcess** is really high, and I don't know why, ¿has any one find this problem?, I don't know what is happening, because using the RP4 it works smoothly, also I tried with a RP1 and it works good aswell, I don't know what is happening, and if I can solve this problem in some ways...

- Edit:  I tried it in Chromium and all the videos played on YT, even the ones of the website works well, so I think that the error may come from UbuntuFrame / wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Comment: Should add that to the question with edit. BTW You do know that the Ubuntu 18.04 release is EOL at the end of May, you should upgrade soon.